# Visual Basic: Not allowed to connect to MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection, mariadb

```
This is a list of errors when the application starts with "Visual Studio 2013"                                                                                                                |
                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Host 'Computer friendly name' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server                                                             |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()                                                                                                                                      |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.NativeDriver.Open()                                                                                                                                           |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.Driver.Open()                                                                                                                                                 |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)                                                                                                          |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()                                                                                                                               |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()                                                                                                                                    |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()                                                                                                                                     |
        with MySql.Data.MySqliClient.MySqlConnection.Open()                                                                                                                                        |
        with WindowsApplication1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\(Username)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 8 |
-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Line:8 Form1.vb:             |                                                                                                                                                                     |
                             | "SQLConnection" is a variable I made.                                                                                                                               |
    SQLConnection.Open()     |                                                                                                                                                                     |
                             |                                                                                                                                                                     |
-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
The code i used in "Form1":                                                                                                                                                                        |
                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient                                                                                                                                                                     |
Public Class Form1                                                                                                                                                                                 |
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=;Database=technical;"                                                                                                 |
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load                                                                                         |
        Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection                                                                                                                                 |
        Try                                                                                                                                                                                        |
            If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then                                                                                                                                   |
                SQLConnection.Open()                                                                                                                                                               |
                MsgBox("Succsessfully connected to DB")                                                                                                                                            |
            Else                                                                                                                                                                                   |
                SQLConnection.Close()                                                                                                                                                              |
                MsgBox("Failed")                                                                                                                                                                   |
            End If                                                                                                                                                                                 |
        Catch ex As Exception                                                                                                                                                                      |
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)                                                                                                                                                                    |
        End Try                                                                                                                                                                                    |
    End Sub                                                                                                                                                                                        |
End Class                                                                                                                                                                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
I am using XAMPP to manage the OFF / ON functions, also the configs.                                                                                                                               |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there someone on earth that knows how to fix this permission error? I have been looking for days for a fix for this but found nothing. Please help me, are there another posts about this that got it's answer?

Comment: `XAMPP` and `MariaDB` imply it is a db on the web.  Yet your connection string is for a local db (`Server=localhost`)

Comment: but the xampp server is localy

Comment: As an aside, your `SQLConnection` variable will not be visible outside of your `Form_Load` handler.  You won't be able to use it anywhere else in the program.  You should not keep a connection alive in this way.  You should establish the connection at the time you intend to use it and then dispose of it as soon as possible after your query.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try

MySqlConnection.connectionstring = ConnectionString

After the line

Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection

From the code given, I do not see you are using the ConnectionString at all.

Hope that helps